# Solve: This System of equations for $X$ (does a real solution, exist?)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How can I solve $AX + diag(X)[I-c]=0$ for $X$?

All matrices have real entries, $diag(X)$ is a diagonal matrix with the diagonal entries being the diagonal entries of $X$, and $c$ is a constant, real number.

Note: I define $I-c$ to be resulting in a matrix that has $-c$ (negative, c) in the off-diagonal elements and $1-c$ in the diagonal elements. $A$ is a positive semi-definite (and square,symmetric) matrix.

Comment: How do you define $I-c$? This is a matrix minus a scalar.

Comment: @Daryl Simple: $I−c$ is defined as resulting in a matrix that has $−c$ in the off-diagonal elements and $1−c$ in the diagonal elements.

Comment: @halms it would have been even simpler if you wrote $I-cI$. Do you have any information about $A$?

Comment: $I-cI$ would be wrong! as off-diagonal elements would not have $-c$. How would that be right, @noobProgrammer? will update. $A$ is positive semi-definite (square and symmetric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a homogeneous linear equation, so a solution --- $X=0$ --- always exists.

To determine whether there is a nontrivial solution, here is a brute-force approach. Write $\operatorname{diag}(X)=\sum_{i,j}E_{ii}XE_{ii}$, where $E_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-th matrix in the standard basis of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Let $J$ be the matrix with all entries equal to $1$. Then your matrix equation can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
&AX+\sum_iE_{ii}XE_{ii}(I-cJ)=0,\\
&\left[I\otimes A+\sum_i\left((I-cJ)E_{ii}\right)\otimes E_{ii}\right]\operatorname{vec}(X)=0,
\end{align*}
which is a sparse system of $n^2$ linear equations in $n^2$ unknowns. So, a nontrivial solution exists iff $M(c)=I\otimes A+\sum_{i,j}\left((I-cJ)E_{ii}\right)\otimes E_{ii}$ has deficient rank. Since $\det M(c)$ is a real polynomial in $c$ and this is not a zero polynomial ($\det M(0)>0$), $\det M(c)=0$ has at most finitely many real roots. Therefore your matrix equation almost surely has no nontrivial solution.

Comment: sounds great. so how would i compute the solution in the case that the term put forth is rank deficient? i find the $diag(X)$ and $X$ terms occurring separately, in the equation- as the difficult part to solve for $X$. Maybe multiply by $1/diag(X)$ on both sides?- and then what..?

Comment: When $vec(X)$ is long, there are definitely many software packages for doing this, but solving large sparse system of linear equations is really not my field, so you need to do your own internet search. When $vec(X)$ is short (e.g. its length is $\le 1000$), you may simply perform a (full) singular value decomposition $M(c)=U\Sigma V^T$. If $M(c)$ has $k$ nonzero singular values (i.e. $\sigma_{k+1}(M(c))=\ldots=\sigma_{n^2}(M(c))=0$), then the solution space is spanned by the last $n^2-k$ columns of $V$.

Comment: I see, what ure saying - but now focussing on the second, spectral approach. I am wondering what the next step would be for solving $AX=0$, where the svd of $A$ is known, for solving for X!? Am trying to see the intentof your thought in this approach

Comment: @halms I may be wrong, but I don't think the SVD of $A$ (since $A$ is positive definite, its SVD is actually a spectral decomposition or an orthogonal diagonalisation) is in any way useful to the SVD of $M(c)$.

Comment: Before I accept the answer I need a clarification, I see the final result having a mistake with the dimensionality as $X$ is rectangular! I see that $M(c)=I\otimes A+\sum_{i,j}\left((I-cJ)E_{ii}\right)\otimes E_{ii}$ is of dimension $n^2 \times n^2$ and $Vec(X)$ being $nd \times 1$ dimensional given that $X$ is $X_{n \times d}$ with $d \ll n$

Comment: Also, to back up in addition to the above comment: $2AX+4diag(X)[I-\alpha J]$  has come from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359779/gradient-question and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359717/gradient-contradicting-dimensions-where-is-the-mistake

Comment: @halms For convenience of the readers in the future, if your matrices are not square, you should state it clearly. Anyway, if $X$ is rectangular (say $n\times d$), then in the first displayed equation, the first $E_{ii}$ is $n\times n$ while the second $E_{ii}$ is $d\times d$. Therefore the sum of the tensor product in the second displayed equation is $dn\times dn$.

Comment: @user1551- I agree. I had missed out on the dimensions! Thanks for clarifying the changes in the answer based on this update, and luckily- it did not require completely redoing the answer. great and helpful answer, on the whole.